# Anchor text is lost center align when is add in menu item

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I'm working with Vaadin 14.4.0 and a newbie on this framework. I have a layout with center align and contain compoment menubar like this

```
HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
layout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
MenuItem menuItem = menuBar.addItem("Menu");
SubMenu subMenu = menuItem.getSubMenu();
subMenu.addItem("Item 1");
subMenu.addItem("Item 2");

subMenu.addItem(new Anchor("https://example.com","ABC"));

layout.add(menuBar);
```

All items (item 1, item2) are aligned with center style except item ABC is aligned with left style.

How can I set item ABC aligned center style like other items( item1, item2)? Or Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: I’m just making sure, that you do know that Vaadin 14 is no longer the recommended version to start with? You should start with v23, or v24 (beta). But I assume you need to work with an existing app, and didn't choose v14 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot would help to see the issue more clearly.

Here’s what I get in a Vaadin 23 project:

[image]

Menu Bar items (in the submenus) should be left-aligned by default. How are you centering them? The `FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER` does not make that happen. At least in the above screenshot, it might look like Item 1 and Item 2 are centered, but they are left aligned.

I’m guessing you might have some custom CSS that aligns the item texts, but that CSS is not targeting anchor elements inside the menu.

Menu Bar uses Context Menu internally, so you need to style context menu items. Here’s what should work, placed in your application global styles:

```
vaadin-context-menu-item {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER works with Item 1, 2 but not ABC. I don't know why

Comment: I updated the my answer. Still, Alignment.CENTER does not affect the submenu items in any way.